# Как реализовать напоминание через определенное время?

Tags: java, android

Есть ТаймПикер,пользователь выбрал время, например 13:15:00, сейчас на его телефоне 12:13:00, в то время, которое он выбрал должно появиться уведомление.

Как это реализовать на android?

Дополнительный вопрос: Такие вещи лучше реализовывать с использованием Бэкенда?

Answer (score 3):

Для этого есть класс [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Нужно

1. Рассчитать время наступления события
2. Сформировать [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), который операционная система активирует при наступлении события
3. Сделать обработчик этого интента (скорее всего, вам потребуется BroadcastReceiver, зарегистрированный в манифесте приложения)
4. "Завести" этот "будильник".

   ```
   AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

   // через 2 суток
   long delay = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(48L);
   long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pendingIntent);
   ```

На что надо обратить внимание:

1. В системе есть два вида часов: `System.currentTimeMillis()` - количество миллисекунд с начала эпохи, и `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` - количество миллисекунд с перезагрузки устройства. Если время на устройстве будет скорректировано, то первые изменят показания, вторые - нет.
2. Если устройство "спит", то операционная система выполнит событие с задержкой. Если нужно устройство разбудить в определенный момент, то есть константы [AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) и [AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP). Но даже это не гарантирует высокую точность события.
3. Чтобы отменить будильник, нужно передать `alarmManager.cancel()` с тем же PendingIntent. Повторная установка будильника с тем же PendingIntent изменит время.
4. Возможность добавить к AlarmMangager'у listener появилась только в API 24, в приложениях использовать в общем случае рано.

Как создавать PendingIntent или BroadcastReceiver, предполагаю, что вы знаете, в любом случае это отдельная история.